# Generating XML from Relational Tables

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 / SQL server 2008

I have two tables for parent xml and child xml and they are related by key.
I am trying to generate a XML string by using Linq(or anything works) and those two tables.

Parent xml data : Country
Child xml data : USA, Mexico

I want to generate it like this way.

```
<Country>
   <USA>
   </USA>
   <Mexico>
   </Mexico>
</Country>
```

I have been tried with few ways but I could not figure out.
Does anybody has suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`WriteXml`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml.aspx) method from the [**`DataSet`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwy42y0e.aspx) class should get you pretty close to what you want, and it's a simple thing to do.

[**In C#, it's:**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325650%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
private void WriteXmlToFile(DataSet thisDataSet) 
{
   // Create a file name to write to.
   string filename = "myXmlDoc.xml";

   // Create the FileStream to write with.
   System.IO.FileStream myFileStream 
       = new System.IO.FileStream (filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create);

   // Write to the file with the WriteXml method.

   thisDataSet.WriteXml(myFileStream);   
}
```

So all you have to do is load up your `DataSet` with the appropriate data, and the `WriteXml` method should generate a fairly appropriate XML representation of that data.